# this.name does not output the desired string

Tags: java

```
import java.util.Scanner;

class Description
{
String name = "Pablo";  
public void getName(String newName) throws InterruptedException
{
    System.out.println("Your name is ");
    name = newName; 
    System.out.println(newName);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("However, the creator of this crappy program is ");
    System.out.println(this.name);
}

}

public class Learning {
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("Description of yourself");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Please type your name");
        Description person = new Description();
        String myName = scan.nextLine();
        person.getName(myName);
    }
}
```

I am fairly new to Java. I was reading about setters and this. I expected for it to output "Pablo" in this part of the code.

```
    public void getName(String newName) throws InterruptedException
{
    System.out.println("Your name is ");
    name = newName; 
    System.out.println(newName);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("However, the creator of this crappy program is ");
    System.out.println(this.name);
}
```

However, lets say I input "Steve" in this part of the code

```
String myName = scan.nextLine();
```

It is supposed to pass a parameter to the method getName, which is does. However, when I get to the part

```
        System.out.println(this.name);
```

It prints out "Steve," while it should print out "Pablo. So the console looks like

```
Description of yourself
Please type your name
Steve
Your name is 
Steve
However, the creator of this crappy program is 
Steve
```

Am I doing something wrong?

Comment: What do you think `name = newName;` does ?

Comment: I think you got confused with the scope of the `name` variable.

Answer (score 1):

> It prints out "Steve," while it should print out "Pablo. So the console looks like

No. In your getName method, you changed your name to given name.

```
 name = newName;
```

Hence your `name` is no more carrying `"Pablo"` and have a value `"Steve"` from there onwards.

Comment: But I thought user this.name reference to the first String name = "Pablo"?

Comment: @Pablo Yes, but later you changed to given name right here `name = newName; ` isn't it ?

Comment: Yes, I changed the value, but I did that within the method? I think I might be confused with the use of this.name

Comment: @Pablo Yes, but your method changing the `name` which is at instance level. That's not local to your method.

Comment: @Pablo The `name` in the statement refers to `this.name`. So what you did was `this.name = newName` even though you've written it without the `this`.

Comment: How do I make it local to my method? How do I know when it is at instance level or local?

Comment: @Pablo If you declare `String name = ...` in the method, it will be local. If there is no local variable of that name, `name` will automatically refer to `this.name` if there is one.

Comment: So when I use this I will refer to the local or instance level?

Comment: @Pablo `this.name` is always instance level. `name` can be local if you declared `String name` locally in the method, otherwise it's instance level too.

Answer (score 1):

It is because you have this line

```
name = newName;
```

you replaced value of name with newName before printing it using `this.name`. When you called `this.name` it printed replaced value.

Just replace name with newName after you're done printing name, not before it:

```
public void getName(String newName) throws InterruptedException
{
    System.out.println("Your name is ");
    System.out.println(newName);
    Thread.sleep(2000);
    System.out.println("However, the creator of this crappy program is ");
    System.out.println(this.name);
    name = newName;
}
```

When calling a method (function) of class, `this.attribute_name` is equivalent to simply `attribute_name`.

Answer (score 1):

I hope my answer gives you a bit of an insight on the scope of your variable.

Explanation is found in the in-line comments.

Let me know if you do not understand some comment.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class Learning {
    Description description;

    public Learning(){
        description = new Description();
    }

    /* app entry point */
    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException
    {
        System.out.println("Description of yourself");
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        Thread.sleep(1000);
        System.out.println("Please type your name");
        Learning person = new Learning();

        String myName = scan.nextLine();
        person.description.getName(myName);
    }

    public class Description {  // (0)
        String name = "Pablo";  // name scope is  from (0) to (1) so it can accessible from these places (*)

        public String getName() {
            // (*) here
            return name;
        }

        public void setName(String name) {
            // (*) here
            this.name = name;
        }

        // newName has a reduced scope, so it can only be reached inside this method
        // its scope goes from (2) to (3)
        public void getName(String newName) throws InterruptedException{ // (2)
            // (*) here
            System.out.println("Your name is ");
            // this line modifies the name outside of this method (which is where it was defined)
            name = newName;
            System.out.println("A: " + newName);
            System.out.println("B: " + name);

            // this line modifies the localName (since it was defined in this method) but not the one outside
            // (because it is a new variable bound to this method scope)
            String name = "RandomName";
            System.out.println("C: " + newName);
            System.out.println("D: " + name);

            Thread.sleep(2000);
            System.out.println("However, the creator of this crappy program is ");
            // this refers to the class (Description) not the scope so
            // this.name is the same as name in A: but not the same as the local-scoped name
            System.out.println("E: " + this.name);
            System.out.println("F: " + name);
        } // (3)
    } // (1)
}
```